# Python - TypeError: function takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to add edges between the cities and dictionary with the distance between them.
When I try to compile the code I get to this error, can anyone help me?

```
import networkx as nx

cities = nx.Graph()
cities.add_edge('San Diego','LA',{'distance':0.4})
cities.add_edge('NY','Nashville',{'distance':5.6})
cities.add_edge('Boston','DC',{'distance':0.8})
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your code, put it in code blocks.

Comment: Please share the code for the `add_edge` method

Comment: It's just a shot in the dark, but my guess is that you need to add `self` to the arguments that the `add_edge` method takes.

Comment: Given the fact that `add_edge` is a `networkx` method and that's one of the tags, I'm going to speculate that's what the OP is using.  So the questions about how it's coded are probably wrong.  That said, this runs for me in `networkx 2.0`

Answer (score 6):

I believe your code will work in networkx 2.0 (it seems to work for me), but not in networkx 1.11.

In reading through the documentation for networkx 1.11, it looks like you need to do either

```
cities.add_edge('Boston', 'Nashville', distance=0.4)
```

or

```
cities.add_edge('Boston', 'Nashville', attr_dict = {'distance':0.4})
```

But I can't easily test it on my machine which has v2.0.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a dictionary for attributes then you can do it with @Joel second example

```
cities.add_edge('Boston', 'Nashville', attr_dict = {'distance':0.4})
```

however in this case you will get *'attr_dict'* as an attribute in which you will have your dictionary. Like this.

```
cities.edges(data=True)
```

will return

> EdgeDataView([('Boston', 'Nashville', {'attr_dict': {'distance':
>   0.4}})])

A way to get only your dictionary in attributes is `add_edges_from()`:

```
cities.add_edges_from([('San Diego','LA',{'distance':0.4})])
cities.add_edges_from([('NY','Nashville',{'distance':5.6}),
('Boston','DC',{'distance':0.8})])

cities.edges(data=True)
```

will return

> EdgeDataView([('San Diego', 'LA', {'distance': 0.4}), ('NY', 'Nashville', {'distance': 5.6}), ('Boston', 'DC', {'distance': 0.8})])

Answer (score 0):

this is a good question and relevant for nx 3.1 . You can do:

```
cities.add_edge('San Diego', 'LA', **{'distance': 0.4})
```

btw, python is not a compiled language.